# Multiple Update Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have written two different codes in php and I want to merge it with only one code because both codes are the same, only `UPDATE` Query is different. Can any one help me? and the second problem is `if` Condition does'nt work why is that?

**code1:**

```
 <?php

include("Database/connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM registration,billing_month";
$result = $link->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $regid = $row['Reg_id'];
    $duedate = $row['Bill_due_date'];
    $currentbill = $row['Current_Bill'];
    $arrears = $row['Arrears'];
    $updatearrears = $arrears + $currentbill;

    if (date('Y-m-d') > $duedate) {
        $sql_update = "UPDATE  registration SET Arrears= $updatearrears WHERE Reg_id = $regid";

        if (mysqli_query($link, $sql_update)) {
            //   echo "Updated";
        } else {
            // echo "Could not updated";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Code2:**

```
   <?php

    include("Database/connection.php");

    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM registration,billing_month";
    $result = $link->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $regid = $row['Reg_id'];
        $billingid = $row['Bill_id'];
        $duedate = $row['Bill_due_date'];
        $currentbill = $row['Current_Bill'];
        $updatebill = 0;

        if (date('Y-m-d') > $duedate) {
            $sql_update = "UPDATE  registration SET Current_Bill= $updatebill WHERE Reg_id = $regid";

            if (mysqli_query($link, $sql_update)) {
                //   echo "Updated";
            } else {
                // echo "Could not updated";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `UPDATE  registration SET Arrears= '$updatearrears', Current_Bill= '$updatebill' ..`

Comment: Don't do this. The separate SELECT is entirely unnecessary, and you should never execute a query inside a loop.

Comment: You are potentially open to SQL injections with this code. Always use prepared statements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_Order_SQL_Injection

Comment: u mean i close while loop first and then execute update query? @Strawberry

Comment: how can you help me? @chris85

Comment: How `registration` table joins `billing_month`? What is the common field?

Comment: there is no common field in 'registration' and 'billing_month' however the value of 'billing_month' '1.Current_Dues' and '2.Surcharge' is updated to 'registration' table '1.Current_bill' and '2.Current_Surcharge' when current date is greater then 'due_date' and 'due_date' is a field in 'billing_month'

Comment: In this instance, there's no requirement for a loop at all, just a query, but yes - where using a loop, use it to build the whole query, and then execute that query outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to compare your data. Also add quotes in your value.

Before update into database use

```
 $updatebill=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$updatebill);

if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) > strtotime($duedate)) 
{
  $sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= '".$updatebill ."' WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

}
```

To check error in your page use

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

And Prevent you query by [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: and can you tell me how to combine this two php codes

Comment: just write your second query inside you first code because both code are same and having same condition

Comment: brother multiple query can,t work like this.

`$updatebill=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$updatebill);

if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) > strtotime($duedate)) 
{
  $sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= '".$updatebill ."' WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

$sql_update = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatebill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

}`